# Fast searching a Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pandas dataframe with one column containing string IDs. I am using idxmax() to return the index of the found IDs but since the data is over a million rows, it takes a lot of time to search. Is there any efficient way to search which can reduce time. I have not sorted the IDs currently.

Answer (score 0):

please add a sample of the data you are working on.

the following code snippet will sort the dataframe based on the column and select the first row:

```
df.sort_values('column_name').iloc[0,0]
```